# Prevent asciidoc from converting a file path into a link

Tags: asciidoc

I'm manually converting a MS Word document to asciidoc format.
By doing so I ran into an issue that I can't work around yet.

There is an example where I want to show the reader of how the syntax of a file link should look like.
So I used this as an example:

```
file:///<Path>/<to>/<Keytab>
```

Asciidoc now renders this pseudo link into an actual link and warns me about this while converting my asciidoc document into HTML and PDF.

Usually, I would simply use the [source] element to prevent the link rendering. But the file link is part of a table.

```
[options="header,footer",cols="15%,85%"]

|=======================

|parameter|usage

|keyTabLocation    |file:///<Path>/<to>/<Keytab>

|=======================
```

Is there a way to prevent the rendering/convertion of the file link?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I found the solution. I had to escape the whole macro using a `\` at the beginning.

So this did the trick:

```
[options="header,footer",cols="15%,85%"]

|=======================

|parameter|usage

|keyTabLocation    |\file:///<Path>/<to>/<Keytab>

|=======================
```